# How to modify a commit message after a fast-forward merge

Tags: git, commit, fast-forward

I need to test a feature of redmine and Its crucial that I have to add certain key to the commit message, the problem is that I made a merge and git fastforwarded it so now how I can append something in that commit message ?

Answer (score 1):

If that is your most recent commit, just use `git commit --amend`.

If not, use `git rebase -i`

Comment: I had used `git rebase -i` to squash some merges like this `git rebase -i HEAD~2` but I didn't know it can be changed like that...